# hbase applying patch

Tags: hbase, patch, opentsdb

Currently I'm saving data to Opentsdb, and at some point I get the following error :

```
ERROR [AsyncHBase I/O Worker #13] RegionClient: Uncaught error during de-serialization of MultiAction(batch=...........
```

I did some searching, and found out the cause of this problem at the following website that explains about the cause and provides with a patch file: [HBASE-17924](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-17924)

The problem is I cannot find a way to apply the patch file to my hbase-1.4.2

Answer (score 0):

Those patches are simply Git diffs that allow the bug fix to be added into the source code. If you wanted to apply this patch, you'd have to check out the HBase source code and apply the patch in the following way:

```
git apply name-of-file.patch
```

You can use the optional `--check` flag to do a dry run and detect errors if you wish.

Then you'd have to re-compile and re-deploy HBase.